# undefined reference to YAML::LoadFile

Tags: gcc, yaml-cpp

I'm trying to use the new version of libyaml-cpp and having linker problems (`undefined reference to 'YAML::LoadFile(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'`).

I build the library as follows:

```
cmake -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON ..
make
sudo make install
```

Then I include `yaml-cpp/yaml.h` and call `YAML::LoadFile( some_string );`. My compilation line is:

```
g++ -L/usr/local/lib -I/usr/local/include -lyaml-cpp -std=c++0x -o $@  $^
```

I've tried putting the exact `.so` file in there as well with no luck. Using `nm` I can see a `LoadFile` function in the shared library. I can't figure out now if I'm somehow using the wrong build line or there is something wrong with the library.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's an ordering problem on the command-line. I guess I'll just never understand GCC command-line logic. Simply putting the library at the end seems to work:

```
g++ -L/usr/local/lib -I/usr/local/include -std=c++0x -o $@  $^ -lyaml-cpp
```

Answer (score 2):

Support new yaml-cpp API.

```
find_package(PkgConfig)
pkg_check_modules(YAMLCPP REQUIRED yaml-cpp>=0.5)
include_directories(${YAMLCPP_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(name src/name.cpp)
target_link_libraries(name ${catkin_LIBRARIES}  ${YAMLCPP_LIBRARIES})
```

Comment: Could you explain what the function/goal of the steps are so that people coming to it can more easily understand it?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue by adjusting my `CMakeList.txt`

I had no issues building like stated above:

```sh
 g++ -L/usr/local/lib -I/usr/local/include -std=c++0x main.cpp -lyaml-cpp
```

But using cmake and building via CLion failed for me.

This `CMakeList.txt` fixed it for me (this is just a minimal stripped down Version, but it should give an idea). It assumes there is only one version of yaml-cpp installed on your system:

```
# Projekt Description / etc
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(yaml_cpp)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

# Declaration of package required
find_package(PkgConfig)
pkg_check_modules(YAMLCPP REQUIRED yaml-cpp>=0.5)

# Define the executable and link the yaml libs
add_executable(yaml_cpp main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(yaml_cpp ${YAMLCPP_LIBRARIES})
```

This was the most minimalistic way of getting things to work. I was inspired by [Sinaí Aranda](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11564222/sina%c3%ad-aranda) above.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the old version of the library installed too? It's possible that gcc is looking for that version first, and doesn't consider the new one.

Comment: Yes I have the old one as well but cannot remove it (some other things need it). This is why I though putting an explicit path and/or library name would load the new one first.

Comment: And it does find it. If I put `-l:libyaml-cpp.so.0.5` is doesn't complain about a missing file, yet still doesn't find the references.

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling over this for the whole evening today. As I found no useful info anywhere in the internet, I post my results here:

Using OSX El Capitan with new versions of XCode (7.3) and CLang (Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.29)
Using yaml-cpp 0.5.3

Things I did to make it work:

1. Obtain FindYamlCpp.cmake from the [internet](https://github.com/Astron/Astron/blob/master/cmake/modules/FindYamlCpp.cmake). Save it in /usr/local/share/cmake/Modules
2. Set CMakeFiles.txt to find Yaml-cpp

   ```
   # YAML with yaml-cpp
   SET(YAMLCPP_STATIC_LIBRARY TRUE)
   FIND_PACKAGE(YamlCpp)
   IF(YamlCpp_FOUND)
       MESSAGE("yaml-cpp Library FOUND: yaml-cpp related sources will be built.")
   ELSEIF(YamlCpp_FOUND)
       MESSAGE("yaml-cpp Library NOT FOUND!")
   ENDIF(YamlCpp_FOUND)
   ```
3. Add code to src/CmakeFiles.txt to use FindYamlCpp

   ```
       # Enable Yaml 
       IF(YAMLCPP_FOUND)
           ADD_EXECUTABLE(my_exec my_source.cpp)
       ENDIF(YAMLCPP_FOUND)
   ```
4. Using for example ccmake:

   1. set CMAKE_MODULE_PATH to /usr/local/share/cmake/Modules
   2. Set CMAKE_EXEC_LINKER_FLAGS to -lyaml-cpp

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem, here is my method:
You may have multiple yaml-cpp libs on your system PATH, perhaps /usr/lib and /usr/local/lib, so the project may link the wrong one.
However, it's difficult to clean up the yaml-cpp libs on your system, so you need to relocate your yaml-cpp lib install path.
try:

```
clone the source code
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX='your_own_path' ..
In your CMakeLists:
find_path(yaml-cpp REQUIRED PATHS your_own_path)
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${YAML_CPP_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${YAML_CPP_LIBRARIES})
```

Hope it can help you, at least it did to me.