# yaml-cpp compile error: "undefined reference to YAML::LoadFile"

Tags: c++, g++, yaml-cpp

I'm trying to get a simple test program with yaml-cpp to run that looks like this:

```
// main.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include "yaml-cpp/yaml.h"

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
     YAML::Node config = YAML::LoadFile("config.yaml");
     std::cout << config << std::endl;
}
```

I'm trying to compile with this command:

```
g++ -lyaml-cpp -L$(HOME)/local/yaml-cpp/build -I$(HOME)/local/yaml-cpp/include -std=c++11 main.cpp
```

and I'm getting an error that looks like this:

```
/tmp/ccz0D5ol.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0xdd): undefined reference to `YAML::LoadFile(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Here's the g++ I'm using:

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 5.4.0
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

This is on a linux machine where I don't have root access. I cloned the git repo to `$HOME/local/yaml-cpp`, created a build directory, ran `cmake -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON ..`, then `make`, which created the file `libyaml-cpp.so.0.6.2` and symlinks `libyaml-cpp.so.0.6` and `libyaml-cpp.so`. My cmake is version 3.11.2 if that matters.

Not sure if this is helpful, but I first ran this problem by the maintainer of yaml-cpp as a [github issue](https://github.com/jbeder/yaml-cpp/issues/591), and he said

> It's likely a configuration error; you might be able to get an answer if you ask on Stack Overflow.

I also found a similar question with pretty much the exact same problem, but her [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22139347/2680824) of rearranging the order of the compile command didn't work for me. I get the same problem whether `-lyaml-cpp` is towards the beginning or the end of the command.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should put `-lyaml-cpp` at the end of the command line, after `main.cpp`

Comment: @VTT Thanks, but unfortunately that's one of the many arrangements of compile arguments that I tried. I just tried it again and got the same results.

Comment: Hmm, maybe it is some sort of binary incompatibility then. Which functions does yaml library export? Is yaml-cpp compiled with `-std=c++11`?

Comment: @VTT although when `-lyaml-cpp` is before `main.cpp` there is an additional error that looks like this: `main.cpp:(.text+0x106): undefined reference to `YAML::operator<<(std::ostream&, YAML::Node const&)'`. This error goes away with the `-lyaml-cpp` at the end of the line. Not sure if that means anything

Comment: @VTT I'm not sure if `-std=c++11` was used when yaml-cpp was compiled. I can't find g++ in the Makefile. How would I check?

Comment: I guess you should be able to figure it out from cmake file. Or enforce this behavior by explicitly specifying standard or compilation flags (which would be a better option). If `-lyaml-cpp` is placed before `main.cpp` then it won't be used to fill the undefined symbols required by `main.cpp`.

Comment: SO suggested moving to a chatroom to avoid cluttering the comments. If you have a couple minutes and are feeling generous I'd appreciate some tips there. [chatroom link](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171838/discussion-between-ben-lindsay-and-vtt).

Comment: @VTT you were right about looking into compiler options in cmake! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@VTT was right to point me towards cmake and compiler stuff. When I looked at the results of the original `cmake` command, the first 2 lines said

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.5
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.8.5
```

Even though `which gcc` and `which g++` point to version 5.4.0. I found [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13089688/2680824) which points to [this cmake FAQ page](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/wikis/FAQ#how-do-i-use-a-different-compiler) saying that you need to set the `CC` and `CXX` environment variables to specify a different compiler. So I changed my cmake command to this:

```
CC=$(which gcc) CXX=$(which g++) cmake -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON ..
```

and now everything works great.